# will access disconnect from sql-server if it is idle?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i have multiple users connecting to sql-server-2008 database. i would like to know whether they will be disconnected if left idle?

Comment: SQL Server or Windows authentication? If the latter, I'd expect it to silently reconnect when needed.

Comment: @david whats the difference?? its sql server authent

Comment: You've gotten lots of feedback on Windows Authentication in another of your questions today, but I'll just say here that it's the preferred authentication method in a domain environment, and substantially easier (and more secure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idle Access users disconnecting have been my experience in my limited testing in the Auto FE Updater to see who is in the SQL Server database.  I haven't had the time to figure out where that setting is, if any.

Comment: Sure would be nice to know why my posting was downvoted and to have a discussion about it if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, for one, the antecedent of "that's" is not entirely clear without some rereading. (and no, it wasn't me who downvoted it)

Answer (score -1):

No, they shouldn't be, but if you're running a query against the sql server, there is an odbc timeout property that can cause the query to give up.

Comment: how do i change this property

Comment: open the query's properties, and look for the ODBC timeout setting

Comment: i dont really understand how this answers my question

Comment: You really didn't provide any details about the context in which they are being informed of a disconnect, so it's rather hard for anyone to provide answer that would be directly applicable to your question. We can't read your mind.